# Can efficiency of fusor be improved by scaling up?

Tags: space, fusion

[Fusors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor) are very inefficient, among other reasons because the ions have to be decelerated and accelerated every time they fly out of the fusor, while radiating the energy out. However, what if we could build hundred-kilometer-sized fusor in space? So that ions can spend much more time in the "active zone" inside of inner electrode, not subjected to acceleration. Would that markedly improve device efficiency?

Comment: Does this bigger fusor have the same voltage drop between the inner and outer cages as the smaller fusor? Is the number density of the gas the same as a smaller fusor?

Comment: Yes, so that both density and particle speed is the same,but enclosed volume is bigger. I don't see any technical obstacle to that.

Answer (score 1):

The sun is a perfect big fusor confined by gravity. (and its burns any light nuclei)

The useful **volume** of fusion is a sphere for the sun or a torus for a Tokamak (of order r^3)

The area of confinement is a **surface** (of order r^2)

So when the size increases the ratio surface / volume decreases.

That is why tokamaks get bigger and bigger.

Comment: Not exactly perfect; we do still have the solar wind, after all. But yes, very nearly perfect, and certainly more efficient than terrestrial fusors.

Comment: Allright, except gravitationally bound fusors are too hard to tow into/to build in places where they are needed.